# Split map into two sub-maps

Tags: c++, stl

here I try to split the data from one map into two maps.

I tried to use std::partition first, but it fails because the iterator of map is BidirectionalIterator but the returned type of partition is ForwardIterator.

My question is:

Shall I use partition to split map? or what is the better and standard way to do it?

Kind regards

Comment: Can you show the code that you tried?

Comment: What is the split criteria? Is it related to the comparison operator used to build the maps?

Comment: @Vulcann  You can use std::partition_copy

Comment: Nothing very similar to `std::partition` can possibly work on a map. `std::partition` changes the ordering of items in a collection, but `std::map` has a pre-defined ordering of its contents.

Comment: Thanks very much, map has its pre-defined order so partition shall not be used. it seems partition_copy works for me.